# Avoid re-loading datasets within a reactive in shiny

Tags: input, shiny, reactive-programming

I have a shiny app that requires the input from one of several files. A simplified example would be:

```
library(shiny)
x <- matrix(rnorm(20), ncol=2)
y <- matrix(rnorm(10), ncol=4)
write.csv(x, 'test_x.csv')
write.csv(y, 'test_y.csv')
runApp(list(ui = fluidPage(
   titlePanel("Choose dataset"),
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
          selectInput("data", "Dataset", c("x", "y"), selected="x")    
      ),
      mainPanel(
          tableOutput('contents')
      )
   )
)
, server = function(input, output, session){
myData <- reactive({
    inFile <- paste0("test_", input$data, ".csv")
    data <- read.csv(inFile, header=FALSE)
    data
})
    output$contents <- renderTable({
         myData()
})

}))
```

In reality, the files I read in are much large, so I would like to avoid reading them in each time input$data changes, if it has already been done once. For example, by making the matrices mat_x and mat_y available within the environment, and then within myData testing:

```
if (!exists(paste0("mat_", input$data))) {
    inFile <- paste0("test_", input$data, ".csv")
    data <- read.csv(inFile, header=FALSE)
    assign(paste0("mat_", input$data), data)
}
```

Is there a way to do this, or do I have to create a separate reactive for mat_x and mat_y and using that within myData? I actually have 9 possible input files, but each user may only want to use one or two.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
myData <- reactive({
data <- fetch_data(input$data)
data
)}

fetch_data <- function(input) {
    if (!exists(paste0("mat_", input))) {
       inFile <- paste0("test_", input, ".csv")
       data <- read.csv(inFile, header=FALSE)
       assign(paste0("mat_", input), data)
    } else {
       data <- paste0("mat_", input)
    } 
    return (data)
}
```